# Will eating a smoked steak every 2-3 weeks lead to high risk of cancer?

Tags: food-safety

I cook steak every 2-3 weeks and I'm thinking about buying and using this [Breville Smoke Infuser](https://www.amazon.ca/Breville-BSM600SIL-Smoking-Gun-Silver/dp/B072RCDQJS/ref=sr_1_5?keywords=smoke%20gun&qid=1582147145&sr=8-5) with my steak but I'm concerned about the [cancer risks associated to smoking meat](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/7447916). Should I be concerned? I couldn't find an answer using Google. If you can back your arguments with credible sources, that would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Fritz study is a narrow survey and as such does not apply in any scientific way to the general population. It is a 'reported data' type study, has no random patient selection or group assignment, and has application to only the population studied. This would be classified as C-level evidence compared to B- or A- level. Here's the difference.

https://www.aafp.org/afp/2004/0201/p548.html

As such, the Fritz study is interesting, and sort of sets a pointer or raised eyebrow, but is very little to go on. If you wanna smoke your meat and enjoy it, have at it. There's way worse risks in life than that. Like the calories, lipid changes, and risk of your neighbor objecting to smoke wafting his way every week 
 or two.